# Flatten Table Data

Tags: linq, t-sql

My environement is VS2012, C#

Master table: `Journal (JournalId int)`

Detail table: `JournalLine (JournalId int, AccountId int, Debit money, Credit money)`

each Journal Record has two JournalLine records, one for Debit and other for Credit.

I need the following data for my report:

`JournalId, AccountId (Debit > 0), AccountId (Credit > 0)` for each Journal Record.

I'd like to have a list of the Debit Account and the corresponding Credit Account.

Is there a way using LINQ or TSQL to get this data?
Thanks.

Comment: Certainly there is a way. What excactly is our problem now?

Comment: The answer is yes. If you want more help you really need give more details (like linq-to-what?, class model).

Comment: Next time when you will ask the question, provide more information about what you have tried (no matter how silly your code looks now) and what exact problems you have

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq group join to get lines grouped by journals

```
var query = from j in db.Journal
            join l in db.JournalLine 
                 on j.JournalId equals l.JournalId into lines
            select new {
                j.JournalId,
                DebitAccount = lines.Single(x => x.Debit > 0).AccountId,
                CreditAccount = lines.Single(x => x.Credit > 0).AccountId
            };
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you rock guy.

remark: Single() was not accepted, debugger suggested me to use FirstOrDefault and it works (thanks to you debugger also).

Comment: @user1104916 well, if you always have exactly two lines, then there is no difference at all. Feel free to accept solution :)